# Reading text file with multiple blocks separated by #

Tags: pandas, numpy, text

I have a text file with multiple blocks separated by `#`. The number of rows in each block is different. I would integrate a variable for each block. The text file looks like the following:

```
# a    b    c
### grid 1
  1    2    3
  2    3    4
  3    4    5
### grid 2
  11   12   13
  12   13   14
  13   14   15
### grid 3
  21   22   23
  22   23   24
  23   24   25
  24   25   26
```

I wound integrate `a*c` for each block. Using block one as an example, the result should be `1*3 + 2*4 + 3*5`. Any ideas to implement it using `numpy` or `pandas`?

Comment: Read the file line by line, splitting the columns, and making 3 lists of lists.  Each can then be turned into a `numpy` array.  Finish with a `np.dot` using the 2 columns.  There isn't a `numpy` tool to read all the blocks - you need to do that individually.  The rest is easy `numpy` code

Answer (score 0):

Once you have loaded a block into memory, you'll get an array like:

```
In [115]: arr = np.arange(1,4)+np.arange(0,3)[:,None]                                                  
In [116]: arr                                                                                          
Out[116]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 4],
       [3, 4, 5]])
```

the sum of products is then easy:

```
In [117]: np.dot(arr[:,0], arr[:,2])                                                                   
Out[117]: 26
In [118]: 1*3+2*4+3*5                                                                                  
Out[118]: 26
```

Comment: Thank you for the `numpy` implement. I think my biggest problem lies on the data reading block by block.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer from @Fred Foo, which reads the file quite good.

```
from itertools import groupby

def contains_data(ln):
    # just an example; there are smarter ways to do this
    return ln[0] not in "#\n"

with open("example") as f:
    datasets = [[ln.split() for ln in group] \
            for has_data, group in groupby(f, contains_data) \
            if has_data]

dim1 = len(datasets)

cooling_intgrl = np.zeros(dim1)
for i in range(dim1):
    block = np.array(datasets[i]).astype(float)
    length = block[:,0]
    cooling = block[:,2]
    result = np.dot(length, cooling)
    cooling_intgrl[i] = result
```

This works very well for me.